# Object variable or with block variable not set - Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

[Please press here to see my gif that could provide a better understanding of my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqYoB.gif)

As you can see above that it's kinda a problem, but I don't know what to do, so I am hoping that some of you could tell me what and how to do with this. It's my first time to see this " Object variable or With block variable not set" problem...

I don't have any code to show you because I was using the default way to make bound textbox and then using a subform with lots of subform. (See the gif for the idea of the layout)

It's in danish language, but I think this should be a common problem as everywhere in the world, so...

It's in access 2013, in case you was asking.

uhm... If there're any questions, please ask right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a subform within a subform and you are receiving an error when trying to set the properties of the innermost subform that link it to it's parent form (which I will refer to as the middle subform).

Here's a thought.  Try opening the "middle subform" in the designer (ie do not open the main form, just the middle subform from the navigation panel).  then set the properties.  This has a better chance of working.

Here's some references I used for inspiration, the first of which stresses the fact that the linked "fields" are actually EITHER control names OR field names from the dataset and why it is often best to use control names.

http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/subform/master-link-fields.asp

http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: Well, it works! However there're a new error. Should I make a gif about that new error, so you can "see" what is going on?

Comment: Only if you flag my post as an answer and upvote it!

Comment: Actually, did just figured that I can't vote or set your question as a flag yet... Well, I accepted the answer instead which is what I can do with my current rank. Are it alright?

Comment: Ok thanks.  whats' the latest problem then! - add a new question!

Comment: Okay! It's right there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32989871/you-have-tried-to-assign-the-null-value-to-a-variable-that-is-not-of-data-type-v