# you have tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not of data type variant - access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

[Please press here for see the error in the gif.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYwbR.gif)
This is a new question as I am continue from my last question which can see here: [Object variable or with block variable not set - Access 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986921/object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set-access-2013)

Alright... I'm trying to get the names working, and it works as you can see in the gif. However when I'm adding a new person, this error just popped up and say "you have tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not of data type variant"

And yes, it's in danish language in case you didn't know. 
it's in access 2013.

If there're anything I have missing, then please ask me any question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, the only control on your main form is a list object which is being used to select the person that is to be shown on the subform.

I think this design is causing you difficulties.

Consider removing the need for a main form, by putting the control that chooses a person on the subform.

Also the subforms in the subform also seem un-necessary.  I suspect that you could create a single form based on a single SELECT query that gets all the data you are currently displaying in your small subforms.

Because I can't read danish, it is difficult to understand you data, but the structure of your form actually looks wrong!  eg it is VERU rare to need a person form with a subform that gives their names and is linked by personID!

I often recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHt5Fz7cYrQIIw4EyXkkqPQ) youtube channel and also WROX Programming Access books.  They both have examples of hw to structure a form.

I don't know how much experience you have of using Access, but you may find the above useful.

I commonly  use an unbound combo box in the header of a form to allow users to select a person, and then use VBA code to goto the person and display their record in the form.

This technique is explained here: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-03.html

I hope this helps.